# Ensuring “pointer consistency” after compacting garbage collection

Tags: pointers, garbage-collection, segmentation-fault, memory-barriers

I want to implement a compacting garbage collector for a runtime system that supports multiple threads running in parallel, with no global interpreter lock. My main goal is implementation simplicity. Portability isn't a big priority - I'd be happy with something that only works on x86-64 Linux systems.

Ideally, I'd like my memory barriers to be as simple as `mprotect()`ing the pages whose contents are being collected or moved elsewhere. If this causes a page fault in a mutator, the mutator has to wait until the garbage collection cycle completes - I'll set up a `SIGSEGV` handler that does just this.

However, because it's a compacting collector, when the garbage collection cycle finishes, the object that the mutator was trying to manipulate might have been moved elsewhere. I need some way to ensure that, when the mutator re-attempts to manipulate the object, it will use the object's new memory address, rather than the old one. How do I do this?

---

If it helps, here's a description of my object model. This design isn't set in stone, but it's a good reference point.

Memory is divided in properly aligned 64-bit words. Every object consists of a fixed-length header (1 word), followed by a variable-length body. Objects can be either scalars or arrays.

The header word of a scalar contains the following information:

- **Object size:** The number of words in the object's body. Must not exceed 48. (6 bits)
- **Array flag:** Always 0. (1 bit)
- **Alive flag:** Determines whether the object shall survive the next garbage collection cycle. (1 bit)
- **Constructor tag:** Unused by the garbage collector. Can be used to identify the constructor of an algebraic data type, hence the name. (8 bits)
- **Pointer flags:** The i-th pointer flag determines whether the i-th body word is a pointer to another object. (48 bits)

The header word of an array contains the following information:

- **Element size:** The number of words in a single element's body. Must not exceed 48. (6 bits)
- **Array flag:** Always 1. (1 bit)
- **Alive flag:** Determines whether some *slice* (see below) of the array shall survive the next garbage collection cycle. (1 bit)
- **Array length:** The number of elements in the array. (56 bits)

The elements of an array are themselves scalars, and must have their own header words. The object size of an array element must agree with the array's element size.

An array slice, or just slice, is a contiguous element range within an array object. A pointer into a slice consists of three words:

- A pointer into an array object proper.
- The endpoints of the half-open element range `[from,to)`.

Pointers into arrays can't exist in isolation - they must always be a part of a pointer into a slice. This design has some practical consequences:

- Multiple slices can have elements with the same physical identity.
- Taking a subslice of a slice is an `O(1)` operation.
- Arrays can be truncated or split by the garbage collector, if no contiguous reference to them exists.

Comment: You could try skipping the eager remapping phase and instead try lazy remapping, by creating a routine that intercepts all object pointer dereferencing operations. When the routine detects a stale pointer (e.g. by letting the operation trigger the signal you've set for the old memory page), it will update the pointer that was passed to it (locally and for the caller as well) using a mapping that you created at the relocation phase. This is roughly how Azul's C4 attempts to solve this problem.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: And how do I detect when no  more stale pointers remain, so that I can `munmap()` the page?

Comment: Another possibility that bugs me is that, if I `munmap()` a page too early, that is, while pointers to it remain, the *next* `mmap()` call will return the same page, and suddenly a lot of my old pointers will become (not really) “valid”.

Comment: I admit I haven't given this much thought, but I imagine that during the next mark phase, you could trace all pointers and finally decide whether a particular page is referenced or not. This is basically the principle of a tracing GC applied to entire memory pages (in addition to individual objects). This way, you can probably ensure that a page isn't reachable by the roots when you unmap it and then you know it's safe to reuse it.